# Ftp sync to specified Folder in Brackets FTP sync plugin

Tags: ftp, ide, directory, synchronization, adobe-brackets

I just downloaded brackets, and I'm setting it up right now.
I already got the plugin for FTP sync ( I'm new to this ... ), It looks like this

http://puu.sh/8iYBF.png

my question is, can i sync it to a specific folder on my FTP server or can i just sync it to the main folder of my FTP ?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can sync  a specific folder on your server by setting remote root